# Search dialog doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, search, dialog

I wanted to implement a search dialog in my android project. and I don't understand what I'm missing on showing the search dialog to the user.
Here's the manifest for the Activity that suppose to launch the search:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ArrowsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".Searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Here's the manifest for the Searchable Activity:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".Searchable"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable" >
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
         <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Here's the searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
  android:label="@string/search_label">
</searchable>
```

Searchable class:

```
public class Searchable extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    //  doMySearch(query);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_searchable, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**SO..** how do I pop the search box to the user> what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [`onSearchRequested()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29) somewhere, this will start the search activity declared in your manifest.

Comment: Where do I call this function from? the OnCreate() method in the activity that launches the search?

Comment: Done that, nothing happens. Code:

Comment: I never tried to call this function in onCreate(), maybe it doesn't work. You should try to start the search on a button click.

Comment: I just noticed that you used `OnCreate` instead of `onCreate`. They are not the same, and it won't work in the first case.